# when doing Comparison,is typeof necessary?

Tags: javascript, coding-style

I am a junior backEnd developer.
My colleague do code review for my project.
I write a function as below without typeof.
He recommended use typeof for me when I do Comparison in this case.
I wanna know is typeof necessary in this case and why ??
I am happy my colleague give me some advices.
But I need key reason to push me change my coding style, Thank you.

```
let users = {
  Leo:{
    age:20,
    style:"Fire"
  },
  Kai:{
    age:30,
    style:"Ice"
  }
}

//My version
function getUser(name){
  let user = users[name];
  if(user === undefined){
    return false
  }
  // do something...
  return true
}

//Colleague version
function getUser(name){
  let user = false;
  if(typeof users[name] === 'undefined'){
    return false
  }
  user = users[name];
  // do something...
  return true
}
```

Comment: The two versions should be equivalent, except if you’re using an ancient browser in which [`undefined` is mutable](/q/29742135/4642212). However, the semantics of the code are still not quite clear. Is the point to check if `users` has the `name` property? Then use `if(!Object.hasOwn(users, name))` or `if(!users.hasOwnProperty(name))` instead.

Comment: It is possible in some environments that the global identifier *undefined* can be assigned a value other than the undefined value, whereas the return from *typeof* can't. An alternative is `user === void 0` (since `void 0` is guaranteed to return *undefined*), which is also less to type. :-)

Comment: In this project, there are over 1000 members, but not everyone in this users object. 
And they will be deleted or added in this object, so I need to check are they already in this object or not.